# Configure MassTransit topology - Topic to Fanout

Tags: .net, rabbitmq, masstransit

I'm working on a multi-client RabbitMQ setup and wanted to use MassTransit for this. However, I'm having to configure it (obviously) to do fit my vision of how it should work.

I don't mind MassTransit creating all the exchange-queue bindings as it normally does, however, I want to create a "base" layer before all the mass-transit configurations happen.

I have a few domains that are sending events, then consumers can subscribe to these events like normal. But since I have to shovel events too and from here, I rather have a single exchange per domain to worry about. So my idea is something like this

[image]

So essentially, I make use of the namespace of the events to create the "topic" exchange, which then feed the fanout exchanges as normal. With this setup, I can then do something like this

[image]

I.e, I'll have a single shovel from cloud to client per domain (Actually two shovels, one for the other direction as well)

Is there a way to get MassTransit to do this or should I just go with regular RabbitMQ ?
I'd really like to use MassTransit do to how easy it makes everything.

I've gotten a little bit close to this topology using this

```
public class ConfigureRabbitMqMessages<T> where T : class
{
    public void ApplySendConfiguration(IRabbitMqBusFactoryConfigurator configurator)
    {
        configurator.Send<T>(
            x => {
                x.UseRoutingKeyFormatter(context => typeof(T).FullName);
            }
        );
    }

    public void ApplyPublishConfiguration(IRabbitMqBusFactoryConfigurator configurator)
    {
        Type messageType = typeof(T);
        string domainName = ParentNameFormatter.GetDomain(messageType);
        configurator.ReceiveEndpoint(
            messageType.FullName,
            e =>
            {
                e.Exclusive = true;
                e.Bind(domainName, x =>
                {
                    x.RoutingKey = messageType.FullName;
                    x.ExchangeType = "topic";
                    x.Durable = true;
                });
            }
        );

        configurator.Publish<T>(
            x => {
                x.ExchangeType = "topic";
            }
        );
    }
}
```

to configure all the events (I loop through all events and apply this), this is close but not quite close enough.

Comment: To be clear, this isn't the right forum. If you're trying to achieve a specific topology on the broker, creating a standalone GitHub repository with where you're at that runs entirely on its own to compare to what you need is a better approach. Cut-n-pasting code with a hope that it's close enough just isn't practical in such a complex configuration that you're trying to create.

Comment: Ahh, I can definitely provide a MVP for this, but you think it doesn't fit into StackOverflow ? Should I ask on MassTransit Github instead ?

Comment: The repository is really what is needed. And SO isn't the place for repositories, so yeah, I'd go there with a standalone repository showing what you're trying to accomplish.